# Connect MySQL workbench to MAMP using socket/path on windows

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

i am trying to connect to mysql workbench to MAMP with socket/path on windows 10

my problem :

1 I don't have mysql.sock file

2 I am trying to find a resource to find a solution but i only get OSX solutions which is  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock.

I don't have TMP file and my sql.sock

Is there any solution to my problem or i have to use an alternative of MAMP ?

Comment: i am new in web devloppement. i am just learning and never used PHP and SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The 'M' in MAMP stands for Macintosh. What you want to be using is [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

You should easily be able to find tutorials for connecting MySQL Workbench to XAMPP. [Here is one tutorial I found](https://interconnectit.com/blog/2010/01/14/using-mysql-workbench-with-xampp/).